# How do keywords work? Where do I put them?

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags

My name is Scott, I am 16, and attempting to learn coding. I have coded a VERY basic redirect page for my friends company, but have no idea whatsoever as to how I add keywords. Somebody told him that you can see what people are searching and give him suggestions as to what keywords to put in. I just basically need to make his website(s) pop up on the first page or two of Google, and somehow maintain this high ranking. I am BRAND NEW to coding of all kinds, so please explain like i'm 5! Thank you in advance to anybody who helps me out! -Scott

Answer (score 1):

Reading through here might help you with what meta tags search engines like to use and see: https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2067564/how-to-use-html-meta-tags

To get a better ranking, also consider creating a sitemap as search engine bots will use this when crawling your site.

Make sure to submit the site to all the major search engines through their webmaster tools so your site gets crawled and ranked.

Comment: So, basically, keywords don't really matter anymore? I read the article, but I am just confused as to how the search engines know which search terms my website should be shown for.

Comment: @ScottW.Stelloh They are still useful to an extent, but quite redundant. Most spiders now scan the actual site content to work out what the site is relevant for in searches.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">
</head>
```

So you just list them in the `content` attribute of the `meta`.

PS: Mind that adding meta tags alone won't guarantee your website being in top search results. For this purpose, you might want to look into [Search Engine Optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) in a bit more depth.